# How to add element inside another element with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, frontend

Hey I'm trying to add `<a>` tag inside `<li>` with jquery and I'm struggling to find the right way.
here is my code example :

```
$dropdown.find('ul').append($('<li></li>').append($('<a></a>'))
    .attr('href', $option.val())
    .attr('data-display', (display || null))
    .addClass('option ' + customClassEtay +
    ($option.is(':selected') ? ' selected' : '') +
    ($option.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : ''))
    .html($option.text())
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like what is `$dropdown`, `display`, `customClassEtay` & `option`

Comment: What about just doing `.append('<a />')`? There is no need to create a jQuery object and then append it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it directly in the list item string.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, appending html to an element that way would require the [.appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method.

```
$('<li><a></a></li>').appendTo('ul').otherChainableMethods();
```

If I had to guess, you're probably trying to do something like this:

```
$dropdown.on('change', function() {
  let $option = $(this).find('option:selected');

  $('ul') //most likely not a child of the $dropdown
    .append(`<li><a class="option ${customClassEtay}" data-display="${display || null}" href="${$option.val()}">${$option.text()}</a></li>`);
;})
```

The option will be `:selected` if you select it and isn't selectable when `disabled`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

The `` `${}` `` are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to add an `<a></a>` into `<li></li>` right? But from your code above it would not work why? Because the `<li></li>` has not yet been inserted into the `DOM` tree

try doing this

```js
$('#someElem').append('<li></li>').delay(3000).append('<a></a>')
```

This should work!

## Solution Redefined

### This was tested on [JQuery Official Website](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$('#testingInsert')
// insert the list elem into the <ul> tag with an id that uniquely identified it
.append("<li id='listItem1'>New List Item2</li>")
// fade the newly added list item 
.fadeOut(function(){ 
     // Now search for that newly added list item and add the <a> to into it
     $(this)
    .find('#listItem1')
    .append('<a href="#snoop">A tag elem </a>');

    // That's it, it work perfectly 
}).fadeIn();
```

I hope this help you achieve what you wanted to achieve, as this is just thwack to get things done.

Comment: I did try to doing it but i dont get anything inside the <li>.

Comment: This is what i get generated for example:  <li data-value="/cs/" class="option cs">Čeština</li> i just wanna try to add inside this the <a> tag

Comment: I have triad running the code and i discovered with the above approach it will not work just use this method instead since all you want to achieve is an `<a></a>` inside a list tag `<li></li>` and from the above code is like as soon as you append the `<li></li>` you need the a tag `<a></a>`  to be append too. So, why not you just append both at the same time like so: ```js $('#targetHost').append('<li><a></a></li>`)``` to easy your work and speed up you achievement.

Comment: From [https://api.jquery.com/delay/](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) : The .delay() method is best for delaying between **queued jQuery effects**. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() **is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout** function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.